# how do I perform mathematical functions that may exceed LONG_MAX

Tags: max, modulo, factorial, exponentiation, large-data

how do I perform ( A div B ) mod C where I am calculating A in one function,B in another function,and C is say ( 10 pow 9 plus 7 ) but both A and B may be greater than C,or INT_MAX

Comment: Then you use `long long`...

Comment: what if even long long fails..??as in say A in my calculation comes out to be 10 pow 100 ?

Comment: Then you google "GMP".

Comment: What language are we talking here? Looks like C/C++, but...?

Comment: yes,it is C/C++,,and i can't use GMP if I wish to run it on an online judge / ideone isn't it..?

Comment: Actually there are modular arithmetic ways or short-cut tricks(not the one that involves converting numbers into strings and do string multiplication etc and back, please..),but they are not just working for me ..

Comment: there are, but i don't know how good they are, and to write your own will take you up to half an hour max. your call: search for hours to find something that doesn't work or write your own

Answer (score 1):

if the only problem is the size of the numbers you can use long. if the number may be larger then `long.MAX_VALUE` then you need some function to calculate using strings, or use two or more `long` types, and make your own functions. for example, the plus function will get two `long` types, check if the sum of them is smaller then one of them(meaning they went over the MAX_SIZE), then return an array of `long`, containing to numbers, one for the carry bit, and one for the sum.
here is an example in c#, but it's easy to translate it to c++

```
      public static string sum(long a, long b)
  {
     string sum;

     if (a + b > a && a + b > b)
     {
        sum = (a + b).ToString();
     }
     else
     {
        string aStr = a.ToString();
        string bStr = b.ToString();

        if (bStr.Length > aStr.Length)
        {
           string tmp = aStr;
           aStr = bStr;
           bStr = tmp;
        }

        sum = new string('0', aStr.Length + bStr.Length);
        char[] arr = sum.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < bStr.Length; i++)
        {
           int loc = sum.Length - 1 - i;
           arr[loc] += (char)(aStr[aStr.Length - 1 - i] + bStr[bStr.Length - 1 - i] - '0' * 2);

           if (arr[loc] > '9')
           {
              arr[loc - 1] = '1';
              arr[loc] = (char)(arr[loc] - '9' - 1);
           }
        }

        for (int i = bStr.Length ; i < aStr.Length; i++)
        {
           int loc = sum.Length - 1 - i;
           arr[loc] += (char)(aStr[aStr.Length - 1 - i] - '0');


           if (arr[loc] > '9')
           {
              arr[loc - 1] = '1';
              arr[loc] = (char)(arr[loc] - '9' - 1);
           }
        }

        sum = new string(arr);

     }

     return sum;
  }
}
```